# Align validation error message in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have a problem to align the validation message in yii2.

**Rules:**

```
return [
[['text','subject'], 'required'],
]
```

**Views:**

```
<?= $form->field($ticket_thread, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
                                'options' => ['rows' => 4],
                                'preset' => 'basic'
                        ])->label(false)  ?>
```

This is showing the validation error message below of the textarea.What want is need to align right side which i dont know.
I tried like

```
<td>above form field</td><td><?= Html::error($ticket_thread, 'text')?></td>
```

Even this also does not work.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In View you have to add **error**

```
<?= $form->field($ticket_thread, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
                                'options' => ['rows' => 4],
                                'preset' => 'basic'
                        ])->label(false)->error(false)  ?>
```

You can use **errorSummary** to get particular DOM error.

```
<td>fields</td><td><?= $form->errorSummary($ticket_thread, ['attributes'=>['text']])?></td>
```

For more information check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the template attribute in the ActiveField class. Here's the docs:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html

It basically will allow you to say how you want to place the elements of each field.

Then, if you want to align it, it should be done with CSS, is has nothing to do with Yii.

Comment: $form->field itself brings html div and error content..Where can i add the CSS?

Comment: You can add the css in the same view (not recommended). The best thing you can do is create a separate CSS file for your styles and add it via client script: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#register-css

Comment: Thank you ..let me try this

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it did help you ;)